# Unable to remove dependency from project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

In my project I can see one dependency in parent pom.xml's Dependency Hierarchy section. Its scope is Provided. I am trying to remove that dependency through 'Dependency Hierarchy' by right clicking on that dependency name and selecting 'Exclude Maven Artifact..' option. But after doing it, still it is available. I have not added this dependency in my project using  tag. I have no idea from where this dependency is coming. Can anyone help me to remove this dependency?

Comment: find it in .m2 and remove it from your local repository(if you are in windows)

Comment: What do you mean by 'it is available'? When you didn't specify it as dependency, it should not be available, even if it is specified in parent's dependencyManagement.

Comment: @SilverNak - means I can see that dependency in Dependency Hierarchy.

Comment: @Generic - I did it but still it is visible.

Comment: can you share your pom.xml and the parent'S pom.xml, please?

Comment: @SilverNak - I am extremely sorry, but I can not share this file.

Comment: me be it comes from your other dependency

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's dependency hierarchy should print, which dependency added it as a transitive dependency.

I suggest manually excluding it in the pom.xml (sometimes Eclipse's exclude from project can do weird things), by using the `<exclude>` on your `<dependency>`

See [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)